# AttributeError: 'Label' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, get, label

Tengo necesito ayuda con la "def alta()" que tiene que dar de alta registros dentro de mysql, me da un error y no entiendo por que.
La "def borrar() toma los datos de la misma manera, en otra pestaña y no tiene error.

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/home/fran/Python-3.9.0/Curso/Curso UTN/Nivel inicial/Entrega/AgendacLogin.py", line 99, in alta
    dato1 = (date(int(e2.get()),int(e3.get()),int(e4.get())),e5.get()).

AttributeError: 'Label' object has no attribute 'get'
```

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from datetime import date
from datetime import datetime
import mysql.connector

users = {"Fran":123,
        "Heber":333,
        "Flor":684,
        "Julian":632,
        "Fer":444
}
logins = 3
ingreso = False

while logins > 0 and ingreso == False:

    usuario = input("Ingrese su usuario: ")
    contraseña = int(input("Ingrese su contraseña: "))

    if usuario in users:
        if contraseña == users[usuario]:
         
            agenda = Tk()
            agenda.title = ("Agenda")
            vari = StringVar()
            varip = StringVar()
            hoy = date.today()

            #Pannel de pestañas
            pestaña = ttk.Notebook(agenda)
            pestaña.grid(column=0, row=1)
            pestaña2 = ttk.Notebook(agenda)
            pestaña2.grid(column=0, row=9)
            p1 = ttk.Frame(pestaña)   
            p2 = ttk.Frame(pestaña)   
            p3 = ttk.Frame(pestaña)
            p4 = ttk.Frame(pestaña)
            p5 = ttk.Frame(pestaña)
            p6 = ttk.Frame(pestaña2)
            p7 = ttk.Frame(pestaña)
            pestaña.add(p1, text='Ingreso')
            pestaña.add(p2, text='Agregar')
            pestaña.add(p3, text='Modificar')
            pestaña.add(p4, text='Eliminar')
            pestaña.add(p5, text='Evento hoy')
            pestaña2.add(p6, text='Treeview')
            pestaña.add(p7, text='Aux')

            #Pestaña Ingreso (p1)

            Label(p1, text= hoy.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')).grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=N)
            Label(p1, text="Hoy es:").grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=N)
            Label(p1, text="Bienvenido: ").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N)

            e1 = Label(p1, textvariable = vari, padx =50, pady= 5)

            e1.grid(row=0, column=1)

            vari.set("")
            vari.set(usuario)
            

            #Pestaña Agregar (p2)

            Label(p2, text= hoy.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')).grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N)
            Label(p2, text="Hoy es:").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N)
            Label(p2, text="Año:").grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=N)
            Label(p2, text="Mes:").grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=N)
            Label(p2, text="Día:").grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=N)
            Label(p2, text="Ingrese el recordatorio:").grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=N)

            #Caracteristica de campos.

            e2 = Entry(p2)
            e3 = Entry(p2)
            e4 = Entry(p2)
            e5 = Entry(p2)

            #Posicion de campos

            e2.grid(row=1, column=1)
            e3.grid(row=2, column=1)
            e4.grid(row=3, column=1)
            e5.grid(row=4, column=1)

            #Agrega recordatorios.

            def alta():
                                
                mibase = mysql.connector.connect(
                    host = "localhost",
                    user = "root",
                    passwd = "",
                    database = "Agenda"
                )        
                micursor = mibase.cursor()
                sql = "INSERT INTO Agenda (Fecha,Recordatorio) VALUES (%s,%s)"
                dato1 = (date(int(e2.get()),int(e3.get()),int(e4.get())),e5.get())
                micursor.execute(sql, dato1)
                mibase.commit()
           
            b = Button(p2, text="Ingresar", command=alta, padx=5, pady=5)
            b.grid(row=6, column=1)

            #Pestaña modificar (p3)

            Label(p3, text= hoy.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')).grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N)
            Label(p3, text="Hoy es:").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N)
            Label(p3, text="Año:").grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=N)
            Label(p3, text="Mes:").grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=N)
            Label(p3, text="Día:").grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=N)
            Label(p3, text="Ingrese modificación:").grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=N)

            #Caracteristica de campos.

            e6 = Entry(p3)
            e7 = Entry(p3)
            e8 = Entry(p3)
            e9 = Entry(p3)

            #Posicion de campos

            e6.grid(row=1, column=1)
            e7.grid(row=2, column=1)
            e8.grid(row=3, column=1)
            e9.grid(row=4, column=1)

            def modificar():
                mibase = mysql.connector.connect(
                    host="localhost",  
                    user="root",  
                    passwd="",  
                    database="Agenda"
                )
                micursor = mibase.cursor()
                sql = "UPDATE Agenda SET Recordatorio (%s) WHERE Fecha (%s)"
                dato = (date[int(e6.get()),int(e7.get()),int(e8.get())],e9.get())
                micursor.execute(sql, dato)
                mibase.commit()

            g = Button(p3, text="Modificar", command=modificar, padx=5, pady=5)
            g.grid(row=6, column=1)

            #Pestaña borrar (p4)

            Label(p4, text= hoy.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')).grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N)
            Label(p4, text="Hoy es:").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N)
            Label(p4, text="Año:").grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=N)
            Label(p4, text="Mes:").grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=N)
            Label(p4, text="Día:").grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=N)

            #Caracteristica de campos.

            e10 = Entry(p4)
            e11 = Entry(p4)
            e12 = Entry(p4)

            #Posicion de campos

            e10.grid(row=1, column=1)
            e11.grid(row=2, column=1)
            e12.grid(row=3, column=1)
            "e4.grid(row=4, column=1)"

            #Borra recordatorio en la fecha ingresada.

            def borrar():
                mibase = mysql.connector.connect(
                    host="localhost",  
                    user="root",  
                    passwd="",  
                    database="Agenda"
                )
                micursor = mibase.cursor()
                sql = "DELETE FROM Agenda WHERE Fecha = %s"
                dato2 = (date(int(e10.get()),int(e11.get()),int(e12.get())),)
                micursor.execute(sql, dato2)
                mibase.commit()

            e = Button(p4, text="Borrar", command=borrar, padx=5, pady=5)
            e.grid(row=6, column=1)

            #Pestaña Evento Hoy (p5)

            Label(p5, text= hoy.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')).grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N)
            Label(p5, text="Hoy es:").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N)

            Label(p5, text="Evento hoy:").grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=N)
            e5 = Label(p5, textvariable = varip, padx =50, pady= 5)
            e5.grid(row=3, column=1)

            def proximorecordatorio():
                mibase = mysql.connector.connect(
                    host="localhost",  
                    user="root",  
                    passwd="",  
                    database="Agenda"
                )
                micursor = mibase.cursor()
                sql = "SELECT Recordatorio FROM Agenda WHERE Fecha = %s"
                dato = (date.today(),)
                micursor.execute(sql,dato)
                resultado = micursor.fetchall()
                varip.set("")
                varip.set(resultado)

            c = Button(p5, text="Proximo recordatorio", command=proximorecordatorio, padx=5, pady=5)
            c.grid(row=6, column=1)

            #Aux (p7)

            Label(p7, text= hoy.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')).grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N)

            def crearbd():
                mibase = mysql.connector.connect(   
                    host="localhost",  
                    user="root",  
                    passwd="")
                micursor = mibase.cursor()
                micursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE Agenda")

            #Crea la tabla

            def crearagenda():
                mibase = mysql.connector.connect(   
                    host="localhost",  
                    user="root",  
                    passwd="",
                    database="Agenda")
                micursor = mibase.cursor()
                micursor.execute("CREATE TABLE Agenda(Fecha date NOT NULL,Recordatorio text NOT NULL)")

            d = Button(p7, text="Crear BD", command=crearbd, padx=5, pady=5)
            d.grid(row=2, column=0)

            f = Button(p7, text="Crear Tabla", command=crearagenda, padx=5, pady=5)
            f.grid(row=2, column=2)

            agenda.mainloop()

            ingreso = True
            
        else:
            print("Contraseña incorrecta.")
            logins -= 1
    else:
        print("Usuario inexistente.")
        logins -= 1

if logins == 0:
    print("Acceso denegado.")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bienvenido Francisco!

## Explicación

Primero declaras e5 como un entry:

```
e5 = Entry(p2)
```

Pero luego reemplazas el valor de la variable e5 a un Label en esta línea:

```
e5 = Label(p5, textvariable = varip, padx =50, pady= 5)
```

Finalmente, en tu función intentas obtener que está escrito en el label, pero el widget Label no tiene el metodo `.get`, por lo que da error.

## Solución

Cambia el nombre de la variable donde guardas el label a otra, por ejemplo:

```
label = Label(p5, textvariable = varip, padx =50, pady= 5)
```

Entonces, e5 seguirá siendo el entry que creaste al inicio.